# Safari Web Inspector stops logging network activity

Tags: safari, web-inspector

I'm using Safari 10.0.1 on Sierra 10.12.1.

At some point, usually after ~5 minutes or about 100 requests, the web inspector stops logging network requests under the Network tab.

Same thing happens with the Timelines tab.

I've had this problem since Safari 9 on El Cap.

Any pointers on how to solve this?

Comment: Try use [Safari Tech preview](https://developer.apple.com/safari/technology-preview/). Here Safari 10.0.1 is very hungry, and eat a lot of RAM, I just gave up to use Safari 10.0.1 to my web dev workflow, tech preview is not the solution, but much better than 10.0.1.

Comment: @Vagner Thanks for the tip. Unfortunately, STP also seems to stop logging network activity after a while.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a bug. Please file a bug report with a test case/URL and steps to reproduce at https://www.webkit.org/new-inspector-bug and we will take a look at it!